# Installing Python on a fresh new computer using a python script from another one?

Tags: python

So, for example, I have two Windows PCs that are not connected to same network.
Let's name them Computer 1 and Computer 2.
Computer 2 already has python installed in it and Computer 1 is brand new

I want to be able to install python environment on Computer 1 using the .exe file that we can get from python.org while sitting at Computer 2

Suppose Computer 1 has a .exe file that it received from me. When that exe is run, I want it to install python in their PC

Comment: And ? How can you reach Comp1 if they are not on same network ?

Comment: I would send them a .exe file that they would run and the exe would install python on their computer. That's all that I want. Otherwise you'll see options like I accept the license and all that. I want it to be done automatically

Comment: Then you could mail a link to the installation file from python.org

Comment: No I want that an exe is run and it automatically adds a folder suppose to a specific location'

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need a way to transfer the file form local machine to remote.
2. Execute a script on remote machine.

On Linux, you can use scp for step 1

```
scp local_python_file_or_script.sh  remote-user@remote_machine_ip:/path_on_remote/
```

After this you can use ssh to execute the script on remote machine

```
ssh user@remote_machine_ip  /path_on_remote/local_python_file_or_script.sh
```

PS. If the file is not executable on remote machine, you will need to use ssh and change chmod +x
PS2. You will need to find the equivalent for these tools on windows.